# Does a person have to be in the drivers seat while driving in Virginia?

Tags: driving, vehicle

Does a person have to be in the drivers seat while driving  in Virginia? You do not have to wear a seat belt if you get a doctors note or if your a taxi driver and there is no law about keeping hands on the wheel or sitting in the seat. So can you operate a car legally while not in the driver seat if you can maintain proper control?

Comment: I don't think "driver's seat" has a special legal definition. If you can operate the car from the right side, and you are sitting on the right side, and are driving, then that pretty much becomes "the driver's seat". Are you asking if dual controls are legal in Virginia?

Comment: How would that even work? I can't visualize what you are describing.